# Как сделать снимок содержимого WebView?

Tags: android, c#, webview, xamarin

Nexus 5. Android Lollipop 5.1. Xamarin.

Я использую этот код для сохранения диалогов с m.vk.com в виде изображений. Это именно не скриншоты , а снимок содержимого WebView. Иногда они выходят высотой в 20000px, т.е. значительно больше видимой области WebView.

Раньше всё работало хорошо, но с недавнего времени снимок имеет прежний размер, но на нём лишь видимая область WebView и куча серого фона. Я подозреваю, что причина в обновлении WebView. Как это можно исправить?

```
public override void OnPageFinished (WebView view, string url)
{           
    Picture picture = view.CapturePicture ();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (picture.Width, picture.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas (bmp);
    picture.Draw (canvas);
    MainActivity.Save(bmp);
}
```

Comment: Удалил все обновления WebView и всё работает как раньше. Но решение крайне сомнительно.

Answer (score 1):

UPD:
Перед созданием WebView нужно вызвать эту статическую процедуру
WebView.EnableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();